# Combine multiple "functions" in a pdf hyperlink?

Tags: pdf, browser, hyperlink, adobe, viewer

I would like to know if it's possible to combine:

```
#target="_blank" and #page=4
```

**In my case:** I have a button in a pdf with a hyperlink asociated, when you press the link, it calls another pdf. The problem is that in Chrome, I need to press `Control+click` to open the link... so I want to force a "open in new tab" when clicking the button.

clicking on `https://something.com/file.pdf#page=4`  works but don't open on Chrome viewer

clicking on `https://something.com/file.pdf#target="_blank"`  works but don't open in the page I want

So I need to **combine** both of them to open the link in a new window/tab on the page I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you follow this link:
http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf

You'll find a PDF document issued by Adobe where they describe the different possibilities for URLs going into PDF documents. They also describe how you can combine them, with the regular syntax also used for URL fragments, so I would try:

```
https://something.com/file.pdf#target="_blank"&page=4
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Chrome pdf viewer still don't want to open it... so I will try other ways. Thanks again for your feedback.